# how to reset rotation?

Tags: transforms

[image]

I know, I can reset a rotation with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>. But this resets the rotation always with the pivot point of the object.

But I rotated my object with pivot point cursor : <kbd>R</kbd> > <kbd>Z</kbd> > mouse movement.

And no, I cannot do "undo", because I changed my mesh in the meantime, I just want to rotate it back.

If the cursor wasn't moved, is there a way to rotate it as it was before?

---

Yes, I could change my pivot point to my 3d cursor, but is there a quicker/more elegant way ... ?

Comment: You can align your origin to a face of your object, the Alt R, is there one of the faces that would work?

Comment: @moonboots: i am not sure... :( - meanwhile i changed the pivot point to 3d cursor and that worked fine. i just hoped there would be an easier solution, which i didn't know

Comment: Object > set origin > origin to 3D cursor, then Alt+R

Comment: @Geri: that's what i wrote in my last sentence...

Comment: Oh, sorry. By pivot point I thought you meant the transform pivot point, not the object origin.

Answer (score 4):

Pivoting about a cursor point gives you a combination of rotation and translation, not rotation alone-- all "true" rotation exists only about the pivot point of the object.

If you have rotated about a cursor, then you've changed the location as well. You can clear location changes by <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>.

However, if your object's location is not at 0 before the pivot about the cursor, then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> won't put it back where it was.  If you haven't stored that location somehow, and it's not in the undo queue, then it's gone forever.  Blender won't bother remembering all the places that some particular object has been.

If you need to store a "rest pose" location, there are three ways to do it.

1. Rather than manipulating the object directly, you can parent it to a bone and manipulate that bone.  Bones have explicit rest poses that they'll return to.  This is what I recommend and use.
2. You can store the transforms of the object as a delta.  To do this, start with the object where you want it, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> > *All Transforms to Deltas*.  Now, when you clear transforms (rotation, location, or even scale), it will return to the orientation it had when you created the deltas.  This is not my recommended solution because deltas always seem buggy to me-- there ends up being situations where they don't seem to work right, even though I've never figured out *exactly* what's going wrong well enough to make a bug report.  It may have to do with object transforms being handled very differently from bone transforms by Blender, and I prefer the way that it handles bone transforms.
3. You can parent the object in a state such that its inverse contains the position you want.  This is tricky-- it requires parenting the object while it has no transforms, to a parent with the proper relative position to it, and then repositioning the parent.  This is complicated enough that it should be considered only as a last resort.

edit: I suppose there's actually a fourth way to kind of store a rest position, although I think of it as being kind of temporary: keyframe transforms.  You can go back to that keyframed frame whenever you want to restore transforms.  But this is kind of temporary because you probably want to also be using keyframes to, you know, actually keyframe stuff.  You don't want to have to change frame or paste keyframes with time offsets to return to your rest pose.  Still, this is something I do when I just need to hold onto a particular transform for a short while, so it's probably worth mentioning.

Comment: very nice explained, thx for that. Unfortunately all 3 are only solutions for the "future", but not for now, where i didn't do the things before, which you are describing.

Comment: Yeah, sorry.  Check the location on a backup?