# How do I rotate an object with an off-center origin?

Tags: animation, objects, coordinates, transform-orientation

I've been trying to rotate an object about its center. However, its origin is not located at its center, and so I've tried positioning the 3D cursor at its center, and applying the 3D cursor transform pivot point option. The ending keyframe still results in the correct orientation I want my object to be in, but the object does not rotate in place. So, this still does not work for me as I want it to rotate in place. Are there any other solutions to this?

Note: I've tried redefining my origin by selecting "Geometry to Origin" and "Origin to Center of Mass", but those options mess with my assembly and causes the components of the assembly to scatter everywhere.

Comment: Some images would be helpful... [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post).

Comment: I think this answer, https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/315482/how-to-reset-rotation/315486#315486 , which I recently offered to answer somebody else's question, might be helpful?  Rotation is about the center.  Anything else is translation.  If you want it to rotate about somewhere else, parent it to something else (like a bone) and rotate that parent.

Comment: if you're talking about creating a rotation animation, it's the origin that will be taken into account. If the origin is not where the rotation center is supposed to be but you don't want to change its position, then parent your object to an empty and rotate the empty instead